# How to repair Web Setup Wizard redirecting to 404 Not Found in Magento CE 2.2.5/2.2.6?

Tags: magento2, 404-page, web-setup-wizard

This is a very critical issue.

I recently upgraded from Magento CE 2.2.5 to CE 2.2.6 using the Web Setup Wizard.

The upgrade went fine and the site is working.

When I try to access Web Setup Wizard in 2.2.6, I get a 404 Not Found response.

[image: 404 Not Found]

What I already tried:

- I removed all files and contents from `/var/`
- I cleaned Magento cache
- I tried accessing the setup from a different browser
- Tried solutions such as accessing through http and https and activated/deactivated `HTTP Strict Transport Security`
- The Document Root points to `/path/to/magento/` and not `/path/to/magento/pub/`

Please note that I have a test instance on a different machine, this one was upgraded to 2.2.6 using **composer**. On this instance, `/setup/` is working fine.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You can track from [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7623) as my experience web setup wizard was not displaying in 2.2.5 and not even in after upgrade to 2.2.6. but if you fresh install to 2.2.6 then you will get this menu there.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Web Setup Wizard in 2.2.5 was working fine for me, this problem occurred in 2.2.6. Unfortunately, a fresh install is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create symlink:

```
ln -s /data/web/magento2/pub/setup /data/web/public/setup
```

remove it after upgrade

```
rm -rf /data/web/public/setup
```

Comment: There's no `/setup` in `magento2/pub`